# Using a query to return the most frequent value and the count within a group using SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Say I have a table showing the type of fruit consumed by an individual over a 24 hour period that looks like this:

```
Name     Fruit
Tim      Apple
Tim      Orange
Tim      Orange
Tim      Orange
Lisa     Peach
Lisa     Apple
Lisa     Peach
Eric     Plum
Eric     Orange
Eric     Plum
```

How would I get a table that shows only the most consumed fruit for each person, as well as the number of fruits consumed. In other words, a table that looks like this:

```
Name     Fruit      Number
Tim      Orange          3
Lisa     Peach           2
Eric     Plum            2
```

I tried

```
SELECT Name, Fruit, Count(Fruit)
FROM table
GROUP BY Name
```

But that returns an error because Name needs to be in the GROUP BY statement as well. Every other method I've tried returns the counts for ALL values rather than just the maximum values. MAX(COUNT()) doesn't appear to be a valid statement, so I'm not sure what else to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a pain, but you can do it.  Start with your query and then use `join`:

```
SELECT n.Name, n.Fruit
FROM (SELECT Name, Fruit, Count(Fruit) as cnt
      FROM table as t
      GROUP BY Name, Fruit
     ) as t INNER JOIN
     (SELECT Name, max(cnt) as maxcnt
      FROM (SELECT Name, Fruit, Count(Fruit) as cnt
            FROM table
            GROUP BY Name, Fruit
           ) as t
      GROUP BY Name
     ) as n
     ON t.name = n.name and t.cnt = n.maxcnt;
```

Comment: I just tried this, but MS Access is giving me a "Syntax Error in FROM clause" message.

Comment: Just tried it with the edit, now I'm getting a "Circular reference caused by alias 'cnt' in query definition's SELECT list."

Comment: I tried this again and it gave me some error about Name possibly referring to more than one table, so I added n.Name and n.maxcnt to the first SELECT statement and it worked. Thanks for the help.